# Display issue with Woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have added the following code to additional CSS in WP:

```css
.woocommerce-page.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:hover a.add_to_cart_button, 
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:hover a.add_to_cart_button, 
.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product:hover a.add_to_cart_button {
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
}

.woocommerce-page.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product a.add_to_cart_button {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}

.woocommerce-page.woocommerce ul.products li.product, 
.woocommerce-page.woocommerce-page ul.products li.product {
    text-align: center;
}

.woocommerce .button.product_type_simple{
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
```

And this code displays fine when the Shop or Categories is viewed:

https://www.brighteroils.com/shop/

But the display of the items on the page on the homepage doesn't display correctly and ive been scratching my head as to why its not.

https://www.brighteroils.com/homepage/

Any help/pointers appreciated  *(this is my first post)*...

Answer (score 2):

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product:hover a.add_to_cart_button{
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product a.add_to_cart_button {
    display: block !important;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product, 
    text-align: center;
}

.woocommerce .button.product_type_simple{
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}

.woocommerce li.product a {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Your home page does not have .woocommerce-page class, and both page has common class .woocommerce
so I replaced it. It works fine. 
You can test it in console.
See the screenshot : https://prnt.sc/nbeipi

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I really appreciate you replying and sending your code.

Answer (score 0):

The css for the homepage would be

```
 .woocommerce ul.products li.product .price
```

The homepage doesn't have a class woocommerce-page which on your products page has a class attached to the body called woocommerce-page. The homepage

```
 <body>
```

does not have that class.

Answer (score 0):

add this to additional CSS :

```css
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .price {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
}

h2.woocommerce-loop-product__title {
    text-align: center !important;
}

.woocommerce ul.products li.product a.button {
    float: none !important;
    margin-right: 0px !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking time to reply to my first post. Appreciate it. Thanks